# How to insert data in SQLite in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I'm very new to SQLite and Swift. I have followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@imbilalhassan/saving-data-in-sqlite-db-in-ios-using-swift-4-76b743d3ce0e

but I want ID to auto-increment by SQLite.

```
// Model

struct PersonModel {
    
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let phone: String?
    let address: String?
    
}

// DBManager

import Foundation
import UIKit
import SQLite3

class DBManager
{
    init()
    {
        db = openDatabase()
        createTable()
    }

    let dbPath: String = "myDb.sqlite"
    var db:OpaquePointer?
    
    // MARK: - Open DataBase

    func openDatabase() -> OpaquePointer?
    {
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent(dbPath)
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK
        {
            print("error opening database")
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(dbPath)")
            return db
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Create Table
    
    func createTable() {
        let createTableString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, phone TEXT, address TEXT);"
        var createTableStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createTableString, -1, &createTableStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            if sqlite3_step(createTableStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
            {
                print("person table created.")
            } else {
                print("person table could not be created.")
            }
        } else {
            print("CREATE TABLE statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(createTableStatement)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Insert
    
    func insert(firstName: String, lastName: String, phone: String, address: String)
    {
        
        let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO person (id, firstName, lastName, phone, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
        var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, (firstName as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, (lastName as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, (phone as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, (address as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            
            if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not insert row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Read
    
    func read() -> [PersonModel] {
        let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM person;"
        var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        var psns : [PersonModel] = []
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
                let id = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
                let firstName = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1)))
                let lastName = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 2)))
                let phone = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 3)))
                let address = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 4))) // this is where i'm getting error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
                
                psns.append(PersonModel(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, phone: phone, address: address))
                print("Query Result:")
                print("\(id) | \(firstName) | \(lastName) | \(phone) | \(address)")
            }
        } else {
            print("SELECT statement could not be prepared")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
        return psns
    }
    
    // MARK: - Delete
    
    func deleteByID(id:Int) {
        let deleteStatementStirng = "DELETE FROM person WHERE Id = ?;"
        var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatementStirng, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStatement, 1, Int32(id))
            if sqlite3_step(deleteStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully deleted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not delete row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("DELETE statement could not be prepared")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement)
    }
    
}

// ViewController

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFirstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtLastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPhoneNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnSave: UIButton!
    
    var db: DBManager = DBManager()
    var persons: [PersonModel] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    func setUpDataBase() {
        
        db.insert(firstName: txtFirstName.text ?? "", lastName: txtLastName.text ?? "", phone: txtPhoneNumber.text ?? "", address: txtAddress.text ?? "")
        
        persons = db.read()
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Button Save Event

    @IBAction func btnSave_Event(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        setUpDataBase()
    }
}
```

when I insert data in SQLite, in `func read()`, line:

```
let address = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 4)))
```

is throwing error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.

I'm adding value in address textField and still getting this error, also I have no idea if this is right approach for auto-increment ID. could anyone help me out ?

**UPDATE**

as per @Joakim Danielson suggestion I solved the issue:

```
// MARK: - Insert
    
    func insert(firstName: String, lastName: String, phone: String, address: String)
    {
        
        let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName, phone, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
        var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, (firstName as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, (lastName as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, (phone as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, (address as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            
            if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not insert row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Read
    
    func read() -> [PersonModel] {
        let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM person;"
        var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        var psns : [PersonModel] = []
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
                let id = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
                let firstName = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1)))
                let lastName = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 2)))
                let phone = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 3)))
                let address = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 4)))
                
                psns.append(PersonModel(id: Int(id), firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, phone: phone, address: address))
                print("Query Result:")
                print("\(id) | \(firstName) | \(lastName) | \(phone) | \(address)")
            }
        } else {
            print("SELECT statement could not be prepared")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
        return psns
    }
```

Comment: In the bind text I use : stringVar.cString(using: .utf8) to convert Swift String to null terminated String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the `id` attribute in your SQL insert statement since it will be automatically handled by the db engine. So change your insert statement to

```
let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName, phone, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
```

When I did this I could run your database related code in a playground and reading values successfully without any runtime error. If you are still getting *Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value* error then there is something else that is incorrect, perhaps related to your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would recoomend to use Swift package manager to install **SQlite3** module by writing the following to your package file:

```swift
// Package.swift 
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", from: "0.14.1")
]
```

Build your project: `$ swift build`

Using a third-party library to manage your database is a common way to access data stored in a Database, it allow you to perform any operation (insert, read, delete) without using string statements, this through by differents methods such as **`Table`**, `prepare`, `insert`, `filter`, etc... One of the key features is that you can set different types of *fields* depending on your data (string, numbers, datetime, arrays) and create any required model structure.

```swift
struct PersonModel {
    
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let phone: String?
    let address: String?
}

import Foundation
import UIKit
import SQLite3

class DBManager
{
    init()
    {
        db = openDatabase()
        createTable()
    }

    let dbPath: String = "myDb.sqlite"
    var db:OpaquePointer?

    func openDatabase() -> OpaquePointer?
    {
        let fileURL = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        var db = try? Connection(dbPath)
    }
    func createTable() {
        let createTableString = Table("person")
        let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
        let firstName = Expression<String?>("firstname")
        let lastName = Expression<String>("lastname")
        let phone = Expression<String>("phone")
        let address = Expression<String>("address")

        try! db?.run(users.create(ifNotExists: true, block: { (table) in
            table.column(id, primaryKey: true)
            table.column(firstName)
            table.column(lastName)
            table.column(phone, unique: true)
            table.column(address)
        }))
    }

    func insert(firstName: String, lastName: String, phone: String, address: String, person: Table)
    {
        let insert = person.insert("firstname" <- firstName, "lastname" <- lastName, "phone" <- phone, "address" <- address)
        let rowid = (try! db?.run(insert))!
    }
    
    func read(person: Table) -> [PersonModel] {
        var psns : [PersonModel] = []
        for user in (try! db?.prepare(person))! {
            print("Query :id: \(user[id]), name: \(user[firstname]), second name: \(user[lastname]), phone: \(user[phone]), address: \(user[address])")
        }
        return psns
    }
    
    func deleteByID(id:Int, person: Table) {
        try! db?.run(person.filter(id).delete())
    }
    
}
```

note: method used to create a database table `createTable` is equivalent to this sentence

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "firstname" TEXT,
    "lastname" TEXT
    "phone" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
    "address" TEXT
)
```

Comment: thank u for your time! I have to use minimum third party integration in my app. but I appreciate your suggestion